# SDK from Amazon for Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I created the empty project and added three libraries aws-android-sdk-xxx (version 1.5.0, in `libs` directory: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/gsg/Welcome.html). But I got error:

> Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonClientException Conversion to Dalvik format
>   failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define
>   Lcom/amazonaws/AmazonClientException;

Cleaning in directory of project and etc - didn't help. I hope for your help.

Comment: Sounds like you picked ones with overlapping content. Read the descriptions on that page.

Comment: How did it happen in empty project, without libraries?

Comment: You said you added three libraries into the `libs` directory. How is that without libraries?

Comment: I mean, I didn't add other libraries (for example apache , json and etc)

Comment: What I meant in what I said initially was that of the three AWS libraries that you added, some have overlapping content. Go back to that page. Go read the descriptions again. If you're still confused, post the names of the three libraries that you included here.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to install AWS Toolkit for Eclipse :)